# More questions from single movie

Tags: discussion

What if I have more than one question from a single movie / TV series, should I ask it in a single question or in separate questions?

Answer (score 6):

## Separate questions.

**Definitely.**

If you ask multiple questions *together* in a single post an answerer might only know the answer to *one* of them leading to *bitty* answers that don't answer the **whole question**...which is the aim.

Be careful not to flood the question queue with too many questions at one time...you can get *viewer fatigue* from too many questions at the same time.

Also, if the questions are connected, take time to get answers to the first which can be considered as they may impact your *next* question.